# can google read title of page stored in mysql database?

Tags: html, seo

I am creating a dynamic website and for each category I want different title and description, so I want to know that if I store page title and description of page in MySQL database or any meta tag.

would Google be able to read those meta tags?

Comment: that depends on if, and how you are adding them to the actual page, and if google can find said page.
Google won't read through your MYSQL database if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks Timothy.
But as in WordPress we do not create individual pages we save page title in database but still they can read by Google.
The same functioning I want in normal php website.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: Yes, if you output your database content as correct html, google and any other search engine will be able to read it.

It doesn't matter in what way you store that information on your server (database, text files, pure html). As long as you return html, you're fine. To answer your question specifically, your output has to look something like:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>$your-database-title</title>
    <meta name="description" content="$your-database-meta-description" />
    …
</head>
<body>
…
</body>
</html>
```